# Control Flow of Event Listeners

Tags: java, swing, event-listener

I was trying my hands on JAVA swing which helps to create GUI applications.So , I have this class called MainFrame.java which is like the controller class.
In bar.java , when 'actionPerformed' event is called and the control transfers to MainFrame.java , and the method tb.setStringListener is called . I am not being able to understand just by implementing an interface , how it became possible to transfer the control?
What is the importance of Interface here? Kindly help Thanks.

Code :

Main.java

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
/**
 *
 * @author Pavan-Kumar
 */
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MainFrame f = new MainFrame();

    }

}
```

MainFrame.java

```
public class MainFrame  {

    bars t ;
    public MainFrame() {
          t = new bars();
          t.setStringListener(new StringListener() {

              @Override
              public void acceptString(String t) {

                  System.out.println( t + " Hey I am inside tbe MainFrame");
                  //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
              }


          });


    }
```

StringListener.java

```
    public interface StringListener {
    public void acceptString(String t);
}
```

bars.java

```
    public class bars {
    private StringListener sl;


     void setStringListener(StringListener l) {
        this.sl = l;   
        actionPerformed();
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

     public void actionPerformed( ) {

         sl.acceptString("Hey .....!");

     }

}
```

How the String "Hey...!" get passed to the MainFrame.java
Output  : Hey...! Hey I am inside the MainFrame

Comment: All the interface is doing is defining a "contract".  It states that any class which implements the interface can perform the prescribed actions as defined by the interface. It also means that `ToolBar` doesn't care "how" the interface is implemented and any class that implements the interface can register interest with the `ToolBar` to be notified when something happens

Answer (score 0):

Control is not transferred simply because you implemented the interface. Control is transferred specifically because you did this.

```
    hb.addActionListener(this);
    bye.addActionListener(this);
```

Implementing the interface simply tells the compiler that the class is an implementation of `ActionListener` and that you can use an instance of the class anywhere an `ActionListener` is needed. When Swing buttons are clicked, they have a list `ActionListener`s that they go through and call each one's `actionPerformed` method. All that is left is for you to give the button `ActionListener`s by calling `addActionListener`. The beauty of interfaces is that the button does not know or care what the `ActionListener` actually is; all it needs to know is that it is an `ActionListener` and it has an `actionPerformed` method.

Comment: When the control comes inside the method :@Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String clicked = e.getActionCommand();
        JButton c = (JButton)e.getSource();
        //System.out.println(clicked);
        if(c == hb && sl != null){

Comment: { …. {System.out.println("Inside the Toolbar");sl.acceptString("..");I am able to visualize until this and after this the control goes to MainFrame :  @Override
            public void acceptString(String text) {
    System.out.println("Inside the MainFrame");
                panel.appendText(text);
I am unable to wrap my head around this .It has a function of the StringListener interface.Mainframe supposed to pass an instance of Interface , that's all, right?

Comment: Can you please explain ?